# Unit tests using groovy for Java REST API's

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, groovy, smoke-testing

Can groovy be used to write smoke unit tests for Java REST API's? Also does groovy provides a testing framework?

Comment: why downvote ? whats wrong in asking this ?

Comment: Because:  *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can test Java code using Groovy(they can interop). [Spock Framework](https://code.google.com/p/spock/) is really good if you want to write groovy.